# What is the type of discontinuity of $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ at zero?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

The limits of this functions at zero are:

- $\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\frac{1}{x}} = \infty $ an infinity discontinuity
- $\lim_{x \to 0^-} e^{\frac{1}{x}} = 0 $ a removable discontinuity

The question is: Is there a special type discontinuity for this case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity

Comment: Can I use the definition of Essential Singularity in real analysis? The problem is that it could be a removable infinite discontinuity or a jump to infinity or another name.

Comment: I don't think it's useful to name limiting behavior more than the terms you've used. Depending on what one is interested in, you could say for this example that "both unilateral limits exist and are different in the extended real line" or "both unilateral limits exist, one of which is infinite". For some situations, the fact that the unilateral limits are different is the important issue, not whether or not a unilateral limit is infinite. For other situations, the fact that at least one unilateral limit is infinite is the important issue, not whether or not the unilateral limits are different.